# Density of A in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Density of A in $\mathbb{R}$
we know that :

> Let A be a part of $\mathbb{R}$.
>   $${ \mbox{ A is dense $\mathbb{R}$ } \iff \forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\, \left(x<y \implies \exists\ a \in A,\; x\leq a\leq y \right)}$$

Do we have the following assertion ?

> $${ \mbox{ A is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ } \iff \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \exists\ u_n \in A,\; x\leq  u_n \leq x+\dfrac{1}{n}  }$$

- If my assertion is false could you please correct it.

Comment: You can drop the weak inequalities and change them by sharp ones, and instead of $\;a\;$ I guess you meant to write there $\;u_n\;$ ...and finally: yes, it is true.

Comment: @Educ I think there is a typo concerning $u_n$ in the second definition

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks but in case if i keep the weak inequalities this means that my assertion isn't true ?

Comment: The two versions of your statement --- one with weak inequalities; the other with strong inequalities --- are equivalent to each other, as can easily be proved.

Comment: @LeeMosher  Thanks you